# Image not updating which is uploaded using volley and glide

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-volley, android-glide

[image: Screenshot of app]I am using `Volley` library in my app to upload image and `Glide` for setting image to textview. I have button to update image which opens gallery and let user select the image. The file is then uploaded in the specific folder successfully, but the image  remains same. I also tried logout and login user which erases the values in `ShredPreferences`, all data updates, but image remains same. The older image is replaced by new in server folder, but still shows in app. It only updates after clearing app data from `Settings`. Why is this happening? does glide stores the cache data? how to get rid of this?

Comment: Try using an `ImageView` instead of `TextView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glide caches the image from server by default. So if your URL is not changing, it will show you the image from the cache. To work around this, you can use RequestOptions:

```
RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions()
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                        .skipMemoryCache(true);

 Glide.with(this)
      .load(YOUR_IMAGE_URL)
      .apply(requestOptions)
      .into(YOUR_IMAGEVIEW);
```

**EDIT** (Picasso)

If you are using Picasso, the same case applies. In this case you should use:

```
Picasso.with(this)
                .load(YOUR_IMG_URL)
                .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
                .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
                .into(YOUR_IMAGEVIEW);
```

Comment: tried it, but not working. the image is still fetched form cache

Comment: I'm not using picasso

Comment: I'm not sure why it didn't work. Maybe you can also read about 'Signatures' here: https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html

Comment: anyways thnx for your efforts

Comment: You're welcome. I had a similar issue some time ago but I was using Picasso. Above code solved the case for me.